# Error happened during deploy process: en_DE argument has invalid value, run info:language:list for list of available locales

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.6

How to fix this issue? It appears while doing static content deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure which language you want to use but `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_DE` isnt valid as shown in your error message. If you want to use `german` please use `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE`.